# Uninstalling program

Tags: uninstall

I have installed Xilinx ISE IDE following this tutorial: [Install Xilinx Ise on the Ubuntu](http://dreamrunner.org/blog/2012/09/12/install-xilinx-ise-on-the-ubuntu/)

and now I want to uninstall it but I have no idea how to do it cause there is no tutorial for this.

Comment: accoording to this: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_1/iil.pdf and this: http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Installation-and-Licensing/how-to-uninstall-the-ISE-in-the-ubuntu/td-p/102082 you only "have to remove the Xilinx directory (don't forget to remove ~/.Xilinx , if necessary)."

Answer (score 1):

On terminal, go to:

```
/opt/folder you have installed Xilinx/.xinstall/bin/lin
```

or `lin64`, it depends on how you have installed it.

Then run this command:

```
sudo ./xsetup -uninstall
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The xsetup script only installs xilinx. Uninstall does not appear to be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a solution since the one by Andreea D has a typo and I cannot comment.

1. Navigate to the folder where Xilinx is installed. In my case it was in `/tools/Xilinx/`
2. Then enter `cd Xilinx/.xinstall/bin/lin`
3. Run `sudo ./xsetup -Uninstall`

Hope it helps somebody!