# Uninstalling VIVADO from Ubuntu 18.0

Tags: uninstall

I have installed vivado on my Ubuntu 18.0 but i am having difficulties in trying to uninstall it.

I tried the two following tutorials but their methods did not work for me.

https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/7-Series-FPGAs/Uninstalling-Vivado-2016-1-ubuntu-16-04-1/td-p/748481

[Uninstalling program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548675/uninstalling-program)

Firstly i do no not have the directory that is mentioned at the second tutorial `

```
/opt/folder you have installed Xilinx/.xinstall/bin/lin`
```

There is no `/bin` file ate the up-mentioned directory. What i have are the following files:

```
/.xinstall/DocNav
/.xinstall/Vivado_2018.2
/.xinstall/xic
```

So any help on how to uninstall it?

Answer (score 5):

go to [install dir]/.xinstall/Vivado_2018.2/bin and run terminal from there and put the ff command:

"sudo ./xsetup -Uninstall"

Answer (score 1):

First go to your Xilinx instalation folder, then look for `xsetup` binaries:

```
<Xilinx_installation_folder>$ find . -name xsetup
```

Outputs would correspond to all installed Xilinx application and their `xsetup` binaries.

For the Xilinx application you want to Uninstall, go to the folder where `xsetup` is located for that application and run:

```
<Xilinx_program_you_want_to_delete_folder>$ sudo ./xsetup -Uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

I had Vivado 2020.2 installed at `/opt/Xilinx/.xinstall/Vivado_2020.2`. There I found the `xsetup` binaries.

Run the command `sudo ./xsetup -Uninstall`

OS - Pop OS 20.04 LTS